# Button location error using Xpath?

Tags: java, spring, selenium

I have to test a dynamic app using a button like that:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="addAnswer(question)" ng-show="question.editing">Add Answer</button>
```

I was trying to locate button with that but I failed

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//img [@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']")).click();
```

using css

> List AddAnswerBtn =
>   getDriver().findElements(By.className("btn-primary"));
>         AddAnswerBtn.get(0).click();

What is the correct line to locate it? I don't want to locate it using class and I wants to use Xpath to locate button location.

Comment: How did it fail? Did it give an exception? Do nothing? Find the wrong element? What?

Comment: i have multiple css class button ... so i dnt wants to use it using class  and using xpath i could not locate it

Comment: browser chrome and xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows it is a button, but your XPath is looking for an **image**:

```
//img[@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']
```

The above is what you are using, with **img** as the element type.

Change this to `button`.

Comment: ok i m using this   getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']")).click(); but it is also not working

Comment: Using Chrome v26 I can find it. You can test to see if Chrome has a problem with the XPath. Open up it's Developer Tools whilst being on your page, go to the Console tab, in the console type `$x("//button[@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']")` and hit Enter. See what you get back. That XPath works fine here.

Comment: STILL IT'S  NOT WORKING :(

Comment: You've not answered the question, do what I said above. Can Chrome find it? Does your web page have IFrames?

Comment: If the element is in an IFrame you will need to switch to it, WebDriver won't find it otherwise. `getDriver().switchTo().frame();`

Answer (score 0):

Xpath doesn't work properly sometimes in chrome browser. Use firefox driver to find it, if you are not sure if your xpath is correct, use Firepath. Or in Chrome Xpath Helper.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath refers to a image, not button.

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//img [@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']")).click();
```

Change this to

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='addAnswer(question)']")).click();
```